# Why IStringLocalizer sometimes returns object but sometimes returns string

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-localization

I caanot understand one thing in IStringLocalizer. Let suppose I have an endpoint that returns Status code 200 and some localized string.

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Test()
{
   return Ok(localizer["Localized Text"])
}
```

if I do this way I will receive an object with some information about this localizer

```
{
  "name": "Localized Text",
  "value": "Localized Text translated",
  "resourceNotFound": false,
  "searchedLocalization": "MyApi.Translations"
}
```

in order to be string with translated text returned, I need to add `.Value`

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Test()
{
   return Ok(localizer["Localized Text"].Value)
}
```

(this returns only 'Localized Text translated')

BUT
If I have some class that has a string property

```
public class ResponseMessage {
   public string Message {get; set;}
}
```

and I assign localizer to its string property, then I dont have to add `.Value` in order to receive corresponding translation

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Test()
{
   return Ok(new ResponseMessage {
      Message = localizer["Localized Text"]
   })
}
```

I would like to know, where in documentation this behavior is described. Cause for now it looks like a magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`IStringLocalizer` indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.localization.istringlocalizer.item) returns an instance of [`LocalizedString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.localization.localizedstring), which is what's serialized when you return it directly in your first example.

For your other scenarii, the `LocalizedString` is implicit converted to a string via its [implicit conversion operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.localization.localizedstring.op_implicit). I assume the implicit conversion operator simply returns the `LocalizedString` value.

You can check the [User-defined conversion operators page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators) to learn more about implicit conversion.